# How to use wp query posts with current post meta value in text widget

Tags: custom-post-types, widget-text

I would like to query information in my sidebar text widget. I added the function. The php query working. (see the code below)

I have single posts with wine tastings. I would like to show in right sidebar which cellar producted it. I added the same custom field key `cellar_slug` and value `somloi-apatsagi-cellar` each post. Code below can show the cellar.

But how can I using on all posts? Every post have different meta value. Is there any solution using current post meta value instead of a fix value?

```
    <?php 

$cellars = new WP_Query(array(
     'post_type' => 'post', 
     'numberposts' => -1, 
    'posts_per_page' => '1',
 'meta_query' => array(
          array(
           'key' => 'cellar_slug',
           'value' => 'somloi-apatsagi-cellar',
          )),
     'orderby' => 'menu_order', 
     'order' => 'ASC'
));


if ($cellars->have_posts()) : ?>

<u1>
     <?php 
     while ($cellars->have_posts()) : 
     $cellars->the_post(); ?>
          <li><h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
               <?php the_title(); ?></a></h3><?php the_post_thumbnail('widget-text-post-thumbnail'); ?><?php the_excerpt(); ?>
        </li>  
     <?php endwhile; ?>
</u1>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is a bit hard to read, but if I understand you on a single post page this should work:

```
$obj = get_queried_object();

if ('WP_Post' === get_class($obj)) {
  $cellar = get_post_meta($obj->ID,'cellar_slug',true);
  if (!empty($cellar)) {
    $cellars = new WP_Query(
      array(
        'post_type' => 'post', 
        'numberposts' => -1, 
        'posts_per_page' => '1',
        'meta_query' => array(
        array(
          'key' => 'cellar_slug',
          'value' => $cellar,
        )
      ),
      'orderby' => 'menu_order', 
      'order' => 'ASC'
      )
    );
  }
}
```

You are:

1. Using [`get_queried_object()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_queried_object) to grab the main post data
2. Using [`get_post_meta()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta) to retrieve the cellar associated with the
   post
3. And running the query only if you have a cellar

Comment: I tried find a way, but dont know why not works:

    `$id = get_post_custom_values('cellar_slug'); 

$args = array(
  'post_type' => 'post',
  'post_status' => 'publish',
  'posts_per_page' => -1,
   'cat' => '25', 
   'meta_query' => array(
    array(
      'value' => $id,
      'compare' => '='
    )
  )
);`

Comment: What you did is, in significant ways, not like the code I posted. You don't specify a `key`, for one, you don't pass an ID to `get_post_custom_values()`, and if you need an array you need the `IN` comparison not the `=` one. Try to follow my code more closely.

Comment: I'm using your code. I appreciate your help. Regards.